# Thunderbird is delaying sending emails

Tags: email, thunderbird

Lately Thunderbird has been putting my emails in my Outbox and never sending them.  I have to go to File -> Send Unsent Messages in order for mail to be sent.  In the bottom-left corner of the screen, I mouse over the icon and it says I am currently Online.

I imagine I clicked something wrong and changed some setting that caused this.  Any idea how I can get Thunderbird back to sending my emails immediately?

Comment: Got to Send Later’s options/preferences and check "Send" dose "Send later" enabled.

Comment: Where do I find that options?

Comment: Send Later is an add on, click on “Send Later” in the status bar at the bottom of your main window and select “Send Later preferences” from the pop-up menu.

Comment: I don't have that add-on installed.